# Finding range of transformation of function from range of original

Tags: functions, functional-inequalities

I'm asked to find the range of $y = f(x-2)+4$, if the range of $y=f(x)$ is 
 {$y| -2 \geq y \geq 5, y \in R$}.
How do I go about finding this? I have no idea where to even start. I'm doing the course online and the explanations were not very adequate, that's why I have made literally zero progress on this problem. I just need some helpful suggestions to get started.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: For what it's worth, your description of the range of $f$ is a bit non-standard and quite verbose.  You can just write $[-2, 5]$ to describe the set $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \;|\; -2 \le y \le 5\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *range* of a function is the **set of outputs.**  In other words, the range of $f$ is the interval $[-2, 5]$ of real numbers, then

- for any $y$ in that interval (i.e. $-2 \le y \le 5$), there exists some $x$ (possibly more than one) such that $f(x) = y$, and
- for any $y$ **not** in that interval (i.e. $y < -2$ or $y > 5$), there are no numbers $x$ with $f(x) = y$.

Now you are considering a new function.  Let's give it a name:  $g$.  It is defined in terms of $f$:
$$
g(x) = f(x - 2) + 4
$$
Any output of $f$ is going to produce an output of $g$ simply by adding $4$ to it.

To make this concrete, say that $f(7) = 1$.  (We know that *some* number $x$ makes $f(x) = 1$ since $1$ is in the range of $f$).  Now, calculate
$$
\begin{align}
g(9) &= f(9 - 2) + 4 \\
     &= f(7) + 4 \\
     &= 1 + 4 \\
     &= 5
\end{align}
$$
This shows that $5$ is in the range of $g$.  Can you figure out *exactly which numbers* are possible outputs of $g$?  *Hint:*  it's an interval, just as it is for $f$.